# How to know if a vector is going to collide a square

Tags: vector-spaces

Let's say on a $2D$ space:
I have $2$ points $A$ ($x, y$) and a point $B$ ($y, x$).
I know that the vector is going from $A$ to $B$.
I also have a square (I have height/width of the square and central point of it $x,y$)

How to mathematically know if the vector is going to collide the square ?

[Example: Vector will not collide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6JhR.png)

[Example: Vector will collide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3VNR.png)

Comment: You can adapt the [Cohen-Sutherland clipping algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Sutherland_algorithm) for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use the implicit form of the supporting line of the segment, let

$$(y_B-y_A)(x-x_A)-(x_B-x_A)(y-y_A)=0.$$

If when you plug the coordinates of the four corners in the LHS, you get four times the same sign, then the supporting line does not cross the square.

---

If you also want to know if the intersection occurs ahead of or behind $B$, then it may be easier to perform a change of coordinates such that $B$ moves to the origin and $A$ on the (negative) $x$ axis.

Then it is an easy matter to detect the crossing (change of sign among the four $y$s) and to locate the intersections of the sides with the axis.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "If when you plug the coordinates of the four corners in the LHS,". I'm a math noob, sorry about that.

Comment: @Gregory: replace $x,y$ by the known values.

Comment: The known values of each corner of the square ? (yB−yA)(xCorner1−xA)−(xB−xA)(yCorner1−yA)=0 ... etc with each 4 corners ? Thanks for helping !